# Lookup with multiple criteria and priority

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am working with different excel files which contain a lot of data from different people. I would like to do a lookup (I know how to use the LOOKUP function) but based on multiple criteria. Let me explain with an exemple, I have a file that look like this (I use / as a column delimiter) :

Name of the data provider / Data / Data code 
John / 55.5 / SSRF5 
Amanda / 55.6 / SSRF5 
Alicia / 54 / SSRF5 
John / 22.5 / ABRD4 
Amanda / blank / ABRD4 
Alicia / 22.6 / ABRD4 
John / blank / FFGR2 
Amanda / blank / FFGR2 
Alicia / 45.6 / FFGR2

Note that I used "blank" to denote the fact that I have entries that have no data.
I have also another file where I have a list of the Data codes, to which I would like to associate a data to obtain a file of the form

Data code / Data 
SSRF5 / ... 
ABRD4 / ... 
FFGR2 / ...

As you can see, I may have multiple data for each data code and/or lack data from certain providers, and I would like to use the Name of the data provider to choose which one shall be used. For example, in this example, I would use the data from Amanda in priority, if not available I'd preferably use John and if I don't have a choice, I'll use Alicia.

Note that I have a finite set of data providers and that I am able to define a strict order between them. Do you have any idea of how I could do that? As my file is very big, I just cannot do it by hand.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I use Microsoft Excel 2010 on Windows 7. 
PPS: I have never used VBA so if your solution needs it, please do not make too much shorcuts. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Power Query Add-In.  It can import data from text files, spreadsheets, databases etc.  It has a Merge function which is roughly similar to a lookup. You can probably chain multiple Queries together with multiple Merge operations to achieve your result.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/merge-queries-HA104149757.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

You can deliver the final result into an Excel table.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to complex for me. I'll continue looking. :-)

Comment: Your requirement is complex.  A Power Query solution is going to be simpler than any VLOOKUP or VBA solution. Good luck!